# Cassandra upgrade issue(could not initialize SIGAR library)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

after upgrading from 2.1.13 to 2.2.9,I noticed the following info in system.log:

```
INFO  [main] 2017-04-25 10:43:30,073 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
INFO  [main] 2017-04-25 10:43:30,084 SigarLibrary.java:57 - Could not initialize SIGAR library org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar.getFileSystemListNative()[Lorg/hyperic/sigar/FileSystem; 
INFO  [main] 2017-04-25 10:43:30,084 SigarLibrary.java:185 - Sigar could not be initialized, test for checking degraded mode omitted.
```

Could any one please advise?
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13519

Answer (score 0):

Try right click the command prompt and run as administrator. And then rerun the Cassandra to see if the issue resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).